# Delete first 10 commits of project

Tags: git

I created a software and saved some informations in a file. I pushed everything to github and after 9 commits I saw that this file was also pushed to github. I changed the .gitignore so that file isnt pushed anymore.

The problem is now that the information can be seen in the first 10 commits...

Can I somehow delete the first 10 commits and nothing else? (So that my 11th commit would be the first one. I already have more commits)

Comment: I have deleted the .git-folder and created a new repo when I had committed and pushed a basic auth header to github.

Comment: is this information private?

Comment: @AD7six yes, but not that private like a password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can run rebase interactively by adding the -i option to git rebase. You must indicate how far back you want to rewrite commits by telling the command which commit to rebase onto.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

- You can reference [git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: i dont get it. I see my latest commits when running this command. I also dont know what I need to do when the editor is open

Comment: @sirzento you can change commit message, just like edit merge conflict commit message.